# tkinter buttons don't grid correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I struggled with python tkinter problem. When I use for loop to grid buttons, they grid incorrectly.
Here is for loop:

```
c=0
r=0
    for i in range(len(e)):
       if c==8:
           r+=1
           c=0  
       else:
           c+=1
       e[i].grid(column=c,row=r)
       c+=1
```

This is the image after processing (It's fullscreen & full image):

[image: screen image]

I was expecting buttons to be 8 maximum in each row, and after 8 buttons next one would be in the next row.

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? line by line? You have too many `c += 1` in your code

Comment: That's true, i fixed it but now again there's similar problem where 1st from 1st row is at 2nd column because button below him is on 1st column, more buttons in multiple rows at the same column seems not to work

Comment: Because you set `c=0` and then do `c+=1` before creating the first button...

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped and now it's working, but if I want maximum 8 per row I gotta type if c==7:

Answer (score 2):

The correct logic is as below:

```py
c = r = 0
for i in range(len(e)):
    e[i].grid(column=c, row=r)
    c += 1
    if c == 8:
        r += 1
        c = 0
```

But it can be simplified by using `divmod()`:

```py
for i in range(len(e)):
    r, c = divmod(i, 8)
    e[i].grid(column=c, row=r)
```